# Kotlin - Put restriction on type parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-parameter

Suppose we have an abstract class

```
abstract class BaseFragment
```

Further, I would like to add a type parameter on the BaseFragment class, like so

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T>
```

Now, here is where I'm starting to run into problems - I want to put a restriction on `T`, namely, I want `T` to be a subtype of BaseFragment. However, when I write

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T: BaseFragment>
```

I get a compilation error:

> One type argument expected for class BaseFragment

How do I resolve this? I've tried `BaseFragment<out T: BaseFragment>` and
`BaseFragment<T: BaseFragment<*>>` but that doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Just constraining to `BaseFragment` doesn't make sense. You need to give it a generic type argument. Do you allow any kind of `BaseFragment`, or just `BaseFragment<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the type bounds of `BaseFragment`. `<*>` doesn't work, because then nothing can ever satisfy the condition. You can use

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T: BaseFragment<T>>
```

Subclasses can "pass the buck":

```
open class Foo<T: BaseFragment<T>>: BaseFragment<T>()
//or
open class Bar<T: Bar<T>>: BaseFragment<T>()
```

Or satisfy the subtype requirement themselves:

```
class Baz: BaseFragment<Baz>()
```