# want to put restriction on method parameter to a specific type in kotlin

Tags: android, list, kotlin, generics

I am using generic list in kotlin. Simply I want to put restriction it should implement one interface.
when I am setting up value of list from other class at that moment also I want to apply this restriction.

```
class CustomView<T : CodeName> : ConstraintLayout {

    private var mList: List<T> = arrayListOf()

    fun <D> updateList(list : List<D>) where D : CodeName{ 
        this.mList = list as List<T>
    }    

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val binding = DataBindingUtils.setContentView(this,R.layout.main)

        val codeNameList = listOf<CodeName>()
        binding.customView.updateView(codeNameList) // This is allowed.

        val list = listOf<String>("data","test")
        binding.customView.updateList(list) // It's allowing me to update value but Ideally it should not allow me because I am sending List<String> and function's expectation is List<T> where T is CodeName..

            
    }

}
```

I referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66298242/kotlin-put-restriction-on-type-parameter). but not understanding how can I solve this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your `CustomView` should not compile. Are you sure you posted your real code?

Comment: okay wait I will put my full code.

Comment: No please don't post your _full_ code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: When I try to compile your code, I get a compiler error (type mismatch) at `this.mList = list`. Did you not get one?

Comment: I have cast it  ```list as List<T>```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233608/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-sweeper).